# Errors on requests for resources, http instead of https and some net::ERR_FAILED

Tags: html, http, browser, https, get

I manage a site and if I open the browser console with disabled cache, there are sometimes errors in queries on some resources. Among other things, errors are `GET https://www.domainname.topdomain/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/AN-IMAGE-150x150.jpg net::ERR_FAILED` These errors are not always, and not on the same resources. One time there was an http request on the emoji script instead of https. And I then saw in the html code that the address had the protocol http instead of https for this script. How can that be? It is a wordpress site, https is set in admin. So it should be https everywhere. The error with http in a script src attribute in html should not happen (have only seen it once, but still ..). Maybe this is more related to just wordpress, I do not know.
For the net::ERR_FAILED errors, I dont see any response headers i the browser.

I dont see any net::ERR_FAILED errors in Firefox, I see them in Chrome and Edge.

Comment: What is the server response for these resources? Also if `http` address in html code, than why would you expect it to be `https`?

Comment: @vanowm , I will check the server response..  According to http in html – it should not be http there, it should be https. It is a wordpress site and the site/home URL is set in admin with https (so I guess https are applied on all URL). I only saw http one time for the certain script, the browser gave error/warning. (I will Edit my question)